# Replacing incorrectly entered dates in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have ran a query is SQL server. there is a name category and every category has a date that it started... however sometimes data was incorrectly entered in the front end so when I do the data pull it returns two start dates per category when in reality just the earliest date should be present. is there any sql code I can throw into this join query that replaces all situations when a category has two dates with the earliest one?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: *is there any sql code I can throw into this join query* - what query?

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix the data, not the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to use the `MIN()` function to get only the earliest entered event when querying your table. You can achieve this my using something similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
categoryName, 
MIN(categoryDate) 
FROM Category 
GROUP BY categoryName
```

However, I am not sure this is what you need since we have no dataset to verify against. Ideally, you can explain in a more clear way, what you need to achieve, and we can help you better.

Comment: what if there is a sub category within the category, my pull was 12 million and I need to maintain with that 12 million there is only wrong date in a few hospitals which makes it hard to check

Comment: Can you give us a sample screenshot of what data you currently have so that we can help you better?